# Android: Не включается "сторонний" tts (text to speech (текст в голос))

Tags: android, kotlin, text-to-speech, tts, android-text-to-speech

Я пытаюсь написать TextToSpeechService. Текст в голос.

```
class TtsService : TextToSpeechService() { private var mCurrentLanguage: Array? = arrayOf("rus", "eng") private val ctx: Context = this

@Override
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    Timber.d("onCreate")
}

override fun onIsLanguageAvailable(p0: String?, p1: String?, p2: String?): Int {
    return TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE
}

override fun onGetLanguage(): Array<String>? {
    return mCurrentLanguage
}

override fun onLoadLanguage(lang: String?, country: String?, variant: String?): Int {
    return TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onDestroy()
}

override fun onSynthesizeText(
    synthesisRequest: SynthesisRequest?,
    synthesisCallback: SynthesisCallback?
) {
    val textToSynthesize = synthesisRequest?.charSequenceText.toString();
    Toast.makeText(ctx, textToSynthesize, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
} }
```

Но когда я нажимаю «Language» в меню «Text to speech output», я получаю пустой список. Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы заполнить его?

ТТС не работает. Я предполагаю, что это связано с тем, что TTS 'не видит' языков.
[image: tts_languages]

Указал язык принудительно:

```
val locale = Locale("ru","RU")
tts.language = locale
```

Но tts всё равно не включается.

В консоли такая ошибка:

> 2022-01-23 19:43:59.295 2966-2966/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
> main
> Process: com.google.android.marvin.talkback, PID: 2966
> java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE pkg=com.forBlind.tts }
> at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1750)
> at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1660)
> at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:715)
> at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.connectToEngine(TextToSpeech.java:821)
> at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.initTts(TextToSpeech.java:772)
> at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.(TextToSpeech.java:744)
> at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.(TextToSpeech.java:723)
> at com.google.android.accessibility.utils.FailoverTextToSpeech.setTtsEngine(FailoverTextToSpeech.java:539)
> at com.google.android.accessibility.utils.FailoverTextToSpeech.updateDefaultEngine(FailoverTextToSpeech.java:714)
> at com.google.android.accessibility.utils.FailoverTextToSpeech.(FailoverTextToSpeech.java:196)
> at com.google.android.accessibility.utils.output.SpeechControllerImpl.(SpeechControllerImpl.java:237)
> at com.google.android.accessibility.talkback.TalkBackService.initializeInfrastructure(TalkBackService.java:1150)
> at com.google.android.accessibility.talkback.TalkBackService.onServiceConnected(TalkBackService.java:1002)
> at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService.dispatchServiceConnected(AccessibilityService.java:501)
> at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService.access$100(AccessibilityService.java:220)
> at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$2.onServiceConnected(AccessibilityService.java:1625)
> at android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService$IAccessibilityServiceClientWrapper.executeMessage(AccessibilityService.java:1852)
> at com.android.internal.os.HandlerCaller$MyHandler.handleMessage(HandlerCaller.java:44)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7564)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)

Что такое: `Not allowed to bind to service Intent { act=android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE pkg=com.forBlind.tts }`??

Comment: Для начала загрузить языковой пакет и протестировать в настройках.

Comment: Что есть "языковой пакет", где его загрузить и для чего он нужен. "Text to speech" (tts) от гугла работает хорошо если что

Comment: У Google свои данные, просто в настройках телефона.

Comment: Захожу в "Настройки" - "Расширенные настройки" - "Язык и ввод" - "Языки" - вижу список языков. Но в списке языков у моего text to speech пусто.

Comment: Обновил вопрос!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Написать полностью свой tts у меня не получилось, я нашел tts от компании google: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:development/samples/TtsEngine/;bpv=1;bpt=0